# What is "LowLagMediaRecording.StopAsync()" for?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

We already have `PauseAsync` and `FinishAsync`.

The `LowLagMediaRecording` can `Start`, then `Pause` and `Resume` a couple of times, and then `Finish` (without using `Stop`). So where would I use [StopAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.lowlagmediarecording.stopasync) / What would I use it for?

Answer (score 0):

[Basic photo, video, and audio capture with MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture#capture-a-video)

> When you are done capturing videos, call FinishAsync to dispose of the capture session and clean up associated resources. After this call, you must call PrepareLowLagRecordToStorageFileAsync again to reinitialize the capture session before calling StartAsync.

> When capturing video, you should register a handler for the RecordLimitationExceeded event of the MediaCapture object, which will be raised by the operating system if you surpass the limit for a single recording, currently three hours. In the handler for the event, you should finalize your recording by calling StopAsync.

> ```
> mediaCapture.RecordLimitationExceeded += MediaCapture_RecordLimitationExceeded;
>
> private async void MediaCapture_RecordLimitationExceeded(MediaCapture sender)
> {
>     await _mediaRecording.StopAsync();
>     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Record limitation exceeded.");
> }
> ```

Comment: So this is only for error cases? The link you supplies says otherwise. But when I call Stop and then Start again, it throws an exception.

Comment: What's the error you get when you call startasync method after caling stopasync method?